# r shiny slider input round

Tags: r, shiny, rounding, uislider

I have a problem with the R shiny slider input. The "Round feature" does not work as you can see in [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4nd6.png). Did I do something wrong ?

```
  sliderInput("Er", "Choose expected return (in percent)",
              min = min, max = max, value = min , round = -1,
              sep = "" , post = "%", ticks = FALSE
          )
```

Comment: What happens if you try rounding the min and max before passing it to the sliderInput()?

Comment: they was round on one decimal places and it still did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify a `step` for `round`ing to work:

```
library(shiny)
min_Er <- 20.31
max_Er <- 23.59
shinyApp( ui = fluidPage(sliderInput("Er1", "Rounding doesn't work", 
                                     round = -2, step = NULL,
                                     min = min_Er, 
                                     max = max_Er,
                                     value = min_Er,
                                     sep = "" , post = "%", ticks = FALSE),

                         sliderInput("Er2", "Rounding works",  
                                     round = -2, step = 0.01,
                                     min = min_Er, 
                                     max = max_Er,
                                     value = min_Er,
                                     sep = "" , post = "%", ticks = FALSE)
), server=function(input, output, session){
  observe(print(input$Er1))
  observe(print(input$Er2))
})
```

[image]

Otherwise, as commented by @Ryan Morton, if you use integers for `min` and `max`, `round`ing will work even if `step = NULL`:

```
library(shiny)
min_Er <- 20.31
max_Er <- 23.59
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(sliderInput("Er1", "Rounding doesn't work", 
                                    round = TRUE,
                                    min = min_Er, 
                                    max = max_Er,
                                    value = min_Er, 
                                    sep = "" , post = "%", ticks = FALSE),

                        sliderInput("Er2", "Rounding works",  
                                    round = TRUE,
                                    min = floor(min_Er), 
                                    max = ceiling(max_Er),
                                    value = min_Er,
                                    sep = "" , post = "%", ticks = FALSE)
), server=function(input, output, session){
  observe(print(input$Er1))
  observe(print(input$Er2))
})
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way min and max are not integers (for example they are rounded to 2 decimal places) and rounding works ?

Comment: @HubertL I'm having a similar issue, so I found your answer very helpful. I do have a follow-up question, using the code from your first example, when you scroll to 20.40% the slider will display 20.4%, or 21%, when at 21.00%. Do you know if there is a way to display the trailing 0s when at an integer or at 0.1? Thanks.